# How to clear the "Launch Application" menu options in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I wanted to ask if there is a way for me to clear the list of options availble on the `Launch Application` menu (see screenshot image below), which pops up on windows when trying to launch a file, that does not have a default application assigned to it.

I was attempting to try and get a html tel link to open via the `ring central` desktop application for windows, by clicking the `choose other application` option, but have so far been unsuccesful, and because of this I have a bunch of unwanted application options to pick from now.

I want this list of options to return back to default, whereby it only shows the option `skype for business` again, therefore if you have a solution of how to do this, I would really appreciate if you could show me.

I tried to google for a solution, but whenever I search for `clearing the Launch Application menu in windows`I get results that talk about clearing start up applications in windows.

Thank you.

[image: Windows 10 Launch Application Menu]

Comment: Run this command `assoc .html`. What output does command prompt show?

Comment: @Biswapriyo hello, when i ran that command in command prompt it returns: `.html=htmlfile`, just want to ask, what is this for?